# What would the steps for CI/CD pipeline be for NodeJS that has two containers

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am reading a book about Jenkins and the author uses Spring Boot, the technologies that he uses are different than mine, I can say that in relation to deployment too ( I don't use kubernetes for example) but I want to use some of the knowledge based on my reality.
My stack and deployment strategy are as follow.

I have a NodeJS project that uses PostgreSQL.
The NodeJS project uses express and handlebars and is in a docker image.
The postgres is on another image.

to run my system I run the two images using docker-compose

Correct if I am wrong to deploy CI/CD in my situation I would have to have jenkins do:

```
-see if the NodeJS project repository changed
-copy the code
-run npm install
-build an image copying all the project source code into the image
-run the containers on the remote server using the docker -h option.


obs. here I am no longer using docker-compose to run the containers.
```

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolves you issues or do share your solution if manage to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

here if the file for Jenkin job

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    imagename = "harshmanvar/node-web-app"
    registryCredential = 'docker'
    dockerImage = ''
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git([url: 'https://github.com/harsh4870/node-js-aws-cloudbuild-basic-ci-cd.git', branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'github'])

      }
    }
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build imagename
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ) {
            dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
             dockerImage.push('latest')

          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy to K8s') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh "sed -i 's,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,harshmanvar/node-web-app:$BUILD_NUMBER,' deployment.yaml"
          sh "cat deployment.yaml"
          sh "kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/ec2-user/config get pods"
          sh "kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/ec2-user/config apply -f deployment.yaml"
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    stage('Remove Unused docker image') {
      steps{
        sh "docker rmi $imagename:$BUILD_NUMBER"
         sh "docker rmi $imagename:latest"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

it has step to build the Docker image using the **Dockerfile**, **Creds** to pull the **Git** code.

You can refer to my repo having a **Node js** **express** example to build the **Docker** image with **Jenkin** config also have **buildspec.yml** which is used by **AWS** code build service similar to **Jenkin** both configs available.

https://github.com/harsh4870/node-js-aws-codebuild-basic-ci-cd

Jenkin Job get **triggered** by **Github** when there is any **commit** event or when **MR/PR** created based on your config setting, you can also do the polling on Regular interval Jenkin check changes.